# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick') I want to find the cause of this error

Tags: html, css

The following error occurs:

Can you tell me what caused this error when copying and pasting the code?

Error message verified by developer tool.

It looks like a simple problem, but the menu bar toggle function still doesn't work.

I've tried searching, but it's not working.

Can you tell me what the problem is?

[image]

```js
const navigation = document.querySelector('.navigation')
document.querySelector('.toggle').onclick = function() {
  this.classList.toggle('active')
  navigation.classList.toggle('active')
}
```

```css
#text_setting {
  text-align: center;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #6843cf;
  font-family: consolas;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container .navigation {
  position: relative;
  width: 240px;
  height: 360px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.container .navigation.active {
  width: 80px;
}

.container .navigation ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.container .navigation ul li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.container .navigation ul li:hover {
  background: #efefef;
}

.container .navigation ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #6843cf;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.container .navigation ul li a .icon {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container .navigation ul li a .icon i {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.container .navigation ul li a .title {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: .5s;
}

.container .navigation.active ul li a .title {
  opacity: 0;
}

.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: calc(50% - 20px);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 5px solid #6843cf;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.toggle i {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #6843cf;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: .4s;
}

.toggle.active i {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DyZ88mC6Up2uqS4h/KRgHuoeGwBcD4Ng9SiP4dIRy0EXTlnuz47vAwmeGwVChigm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8083bd20a5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!----CSS link----->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="left_menu.css">

<!---Fontawsome CDN Link---->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css">

<!----Jquery CDN Link---->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="left_menu.js"></script>



<!-- left_menu_link -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span>
          <span class="title">Home</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
          <span class="title">Profile</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-comment"></i></span>
          <span class="title">Message</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></span>
          <span class="title">Help</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></span>
          <span class="title">Setting</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></span>
          <span class="title">Sign Out</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="toggle">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to wrap in an onload: `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { const navigation = document.querySelector('.navigation')
document.querySelector('.toggle').addEventListener("click",function() {
  this.classList.toggle('active')
  navigation.classList.toggle('active')
}); });`

Comment: As you can see from the snippet I made you, it works when the code is executed after the page elements exist

Comment: Thank you very, very much.
When I ran it with the code you told me, it worked fine.
If there is a problem while developing it, I will ask you again.
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Just post another question on Stackoverflow. There are others that can answer